# how to find the Client id of a text box inside the editable grid view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> i have a editable gridview in which i have a text box and i am
>   calling JS function but i am not getting the client id if the text box
>   inside Grideview is there any way to do it ?

```
  <asp:TemplateField>  <EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txCTFact" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CT_Factor") %>' Width="50px" onchange="validateCTfactor(this);" />  
</EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

> JS  locally i was doing it by

```
text = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txCTFact').value;
```

> but in different browser it's getting different client id is there any
>   generic way.

```
 function validateCTfactor(val) {
            var v = val.id.split('_')[1];
            var text = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txCTFact').value;
            var re = new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,1})?$");
            if (re.test(text)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Required Field with Only numbers allowed with 1 decimal place in CT Factor");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to use `document.getElementById('<%= txCTFact.ClientID %>')`

Comment: Start using a `RegularExpressionValidator` Control. Then you won't have these issues.